# How and from whom did Roger Corman acquire the rights for Soviet Films "The Sky Beckons" and others?

Tags: american-cinema, russian-cinema

I recently discovered a number of American films made by dubbing and editing Soviet films, such as [Battle Beyond the Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_Beyond_the_Sun), [Voyage to the Prehistoric Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_to_the_Prehistoric_Planet) and [Queen of Blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen_of_Blood).  On some of these pages (and on his wiki page), it is stipulated that Roger Corman purchased the American rights to these films, but it never mentions from whom (or for how much).

All I've been able to find is an article [here](http://www.electricsheepmagazine.co.uk/2013/08/24/roger-corman-the-producer-as-jackdaw-filmmaker/), which quotes Corman from an [interview](http://www.kinoeye.org/03/01/yates01.php) in a 2003 issue of Kinoeye:

> In the 1960s I bought the American rights to several Russian science
>   fiction films.

Does anyone know where to find information on this deal, such as who the deal was made with and its value at the time?

Comment: It is quite possible that show business publications, such as Variety, reported the purchase when it happened.  A biography of Roger Corman like How I Made a Hundred movies in Hollywood and Never lost a Dime, might have details, or the books listed here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Corman#Further_reading

Comment: *How I Made a Hundred movies in Hollywood* just says that he acquired [Nebo Zovyot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebo_Zovyot) "*rather inexpensively*". He doesn't go into much detail, but the total budget was less than a few tens of thousands of dollars.